# Is there a <CardView> tag, similar to the <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>?

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, android-cardview

When i was figuring out Material Style, I missed the part where I had to add the support library dependency for Card View.Instead i used a simple  tag.

It didn't raise and error and even the design preview showed cards in it. But when I ran the app on my android device, it crashed and gave an error:

> "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.CardView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.myfirstapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)"

My Android Studio is up to date, so why am I getting this error?
Are there any additional APIs that I am missing and i need to download?

Thanks.

Comment: whats wrong with <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>?

Answer (score 5):

Add the dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Then use the [correct tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

instead of

```
 <CardView>
```

Using  `<CardView>`, the default package will be used,  it means `<android.view.CardView>` that doesn't exist.

Pay attention. The support **libraries v23, require to be compiled with API23**.If you need to compile with api 22, use support library v22.

Comment: what do you mean by `"The support libraries v23, require to be compiled with API23"` ? you mean `buildToolsVersion` in build.gradle? or `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: @pskink It means compileSdkVersion 23 (mandatory). Of course also buildToolsVersion  23 is suggested.

Comment: i used `cardview-v7:23.0.1` with `compileSdkVersion 21` with no problems

Comment: @pskink it is ok with cardview 23.0.1, but appcompat and support-v4 require api23.

Comment: @pskink i know how to use the support libraries for card view. All I want to know is that why <CardView> works in the first place ? You are saying that  it doesn't exist at  <android.view.CardView>, then how come the graphical view of the xml file gives no error. Also, if you just type "<C" in the xml layout file, the first suggestion is <CardView>. Which library is this pointing to ?

Comment: May be the IDE recognises the CardView, but it is an error since it doesn't exist. It is the reason because the app crashes.

Comment: @ArshdeepSinghSaini if you want `<CardView>` to work (since you dont want to type `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>` then just use `LayoutInflater#setFactory[2]` method

Answer (score 1):

use this line

**androidx.cardview.widget.CardView**

insted of **CardView** only in XML code